# Application of a sentence in a situation

Tags: sentence-construction

In the film The Exorcist, father Demien Karras challenges the daemon Pazuzu to get a bigger dare. That dare would consist in abandon the body of the girl Regan and penetrate Demien's body. My interest is to know what would be the correct sentence to describe this situation. The options I imagined are:

> The priest challenges the demon to enter *in his proper body*.
>   The priest challenges the demon to enter *in himself*.
>   The priest challenges the demon to enter *him*.
>   The priest challenges the demon to enter *in his self body*.

In other words, he asks the demon to abandon the girl's body and enter in himself. He wanted to be in the place of the girl, he proposed a change.

Comment: If I were forced to describe it, I would personally choose a verb like *possess*.  (That's not to say you can't use the verb you chose, of course.)

Answer (score 2):

Your third choice, "...to enter him", is definitely the best option; it sounds completely natural to me.

Generally speaking, the verb *enter* either takes the preposition *into* or no preposition at all; so all of your choices with "enter in" sound a bit off.

Also, in the first sentence, *proper* doesn't really make sense.

In the second sentence, the use of "himself" in a phrase where the demon is the active agent makes it read as if the priest is challenging the demon to enter the demon's own body, not the priest's.

In the fourth sentence, "his self body" is ungrammatical; the correct wording would be "his own body".  (However, even after that change, the phrasing "...to enter into his own body" is still a bit ambiguous as to whether the demon's or the priest's body is the one meant.)